# Root Certificate Update Solution - Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

We have an application attempting to run licensing checks via http over the web. The machines this software resides on are Server 2008 vm's with no domain configured.

While tracking what is happening via Fiddler2, after the initial tunnel to the secure site, this Root Certificate update attempt happens and we have this external traffic blocked, so it comes up with:

```
Request Header: GET /msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - DNS Lookup Failed
Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2015 15:30:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 11:30:19.171

[Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "www.download.windowsupdate.com" failed.     System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No such host is known
```

The root of the problem is that it can't seem to decrypt the data to read the licensing to be validated. Is there a way I can manually install the certificates?

I have tried:

Installing the file (msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab) manually by extracting > right clicking the authroot file and "Install CTL".

After doing this, I now get the following GET request:

> ```
> `GET "/fcpca/caCertsIssuedByfcpca.p7c HTTP/1.1"`
> ```

Which of course if blocked also.

To test another machine, we opened access temporarily, ran the software, the updates and licensing ran fine. Even after we blocked access to the internet again, the licensing still works but the attempt to connect to Microsoft's servers no longer occurs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install this CTL in the computer store (instead of current user store)?

Comment: Yes, I just verified that is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed the trust list.  Now it's trying to grab the CA certificate.  You're probably going to have to grab that certificate manually as well.  It appears that this is the certificate chain it is trying to obtain:

http://http.fpki.gov/fcpca/caCertsIssuedTofcpca.p7c

Download it and import it into your computer's Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

It is mentioned in this TechNet blog: http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2011/03/13/deployment-of-the-new-federal-common-policy-ca-root-certificate.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this. I have to get this tested. However, it just occurred to me, would it be more efficient to simply allow these 50+ machines to connect one time, ensure it runs, then disable access again? It's not like these need to be done more than one time based on what I have read...

Comment: That might be wise, as there may be other root certificates that are needed besides this one.

Comment: You could also use Group Policy to deploy the root certificates.  This might be handy because you may have to do it again in the future.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately we do not have these machines on any domain - they are in their own world at the moment.

Comment: Okay - update. Unfortunately, installing it manually did no good. However, we have made the decision to open said sites up and allow the CA certificate grabs to go through that way. 

I cannot locate said list of sites. We found the following links, but we cannot find any documentation from Microsoft or any official announcements. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Links mentioned above
 http://download.windowsupdate.com
http://*.download.windowsupdate.com
http://download.microsoft.com
https://*.update.microsoft.com
http://*.update.microsoft.com
https://update.microsoft.com
http://update.microsoft.com
http://*.windowsupdate.com
http://*.windowsupdate.microsoft.com
http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com
https://*.windowsupdate.microsoft.com
http://ntservicepack.microsoft.com
http://wustat.windows.com

Comment: It looks like you're covering all the URLs for Windows Update except for http://test.stats.update.microsoft.com.  Here is the official documentation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb693717.aspx . From what I read in the following link, it sounds like the process may need to go to other sites to download some certificates.  This article may make some sense of the process.
[Microsoft Root Certificate Program](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc751157.aspx). Maybe I'm misinterpreting it.  Your best bet is to check the firewall logs to see what's being blocked.